# How to assign settings base on testing and production env in flask?

Tags: python, flask

I would like to assign different settings base on various condition such as testing and production. Therefore I want `create_app` accept an argument indicating settings and make `create_app` load different settings as follows.

app.py

```
def create_app(config_file):
    app.config['setting'] = config_file['setting']


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app(production_setting)
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=config.SERVER_PORT, threaded=True, debug=True)
```

views.py

```
import stuff


if app.config['setting'] == 'testing':
     print app.config['setting']
```

test_views.py

```
@pytest.fixture
def client():
    testing_setting['setting'] = 'stuff'

    app = create_app(testing_setting)
    client = app.test_client()
    return client
```

But I get this error when I run python app.py:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'config'
```

Is there any way to pass arguments from `app` to `views`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I'd do it:

```
def create_app(config=None):
  app = Flask(__name__)

  if not config:
    config = 'your_app.config.Production'

  app.config.from_object(config)
```

config.py, peered with the file containing `create_app`:

```
class BaseConfig(object):
  SOME_BASE_SETTINGS = 'foo'
  DEBUG = False

class Development(BaseConfig):
  DEBUG = True

class Production(BaseConfig):
  pass
```

This allows your app to default to production but for instance you could pass a different configuration name when creating the app for development:

```
create_app('your_app.config.Development')
```

For more information on this and a similar example, check out the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/#development-production)